# Compiling a Java USB program with unusual errors/warnings

Tags: java, usb, compiler-warnings, properties-file

I was developing a USB reading Java program to get the name of the attached USB device. This  is the code I wrote:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.usb.*;
import javax.usb.UsbDevice;
import javax.usb.UsbDisconnectedException;
import javax.usb.UsbException;
import javax.usb.UsbHostManager;
import javax.usb.UsbHub;
import javax.usb.UsbServices;

public class ListUsbDevices {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, UsbException, UnsupportedEncodingException, UsbDisconnectedException {
        UsbServices services = UsbHostManager.getUsbServices();
        UsbHub rootHub = services.getRootUsbHub();

        List<UsbDevice> devices = rootHub.getAttachedUsbDevices();
        if (devices.size() > 0) {
            System.out.println("USB devices found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No USB devices found.");
        }

        for (UsbDevice device : devices) {
            System.out.println("\tProduct String " + device.getProductString());
            System.out.println("\tManufacturer String " + device.getManufacturerString());
            System.out.println("\tSerial Number " + device.getSerialNumberString());
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this program, it shows this warning:

> ```
> Note: ListUsbDevices.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
> Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
> ```

I recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked`, and it shows this:

> ```
>  ListUsbDevices.java:21: warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion
>      found   : java.util.L
>      required: java.util.List<javax.usb.UsbDevice>
>      List<UsbDevice> devices = rootHub.getAttachedUsbDevices();
>                                           ^.
> ```

But the class file is created.

When I run this program, I get this exception:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" javax.usb.UsbException: Properties file
> javax.usb.properties not found.
> ```

How do I solve this problem?  How do I set the properties file in Mac? I had set the CLASSPATH with this:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/Users/sakkisetty/Documents/jsr80-1.0.1.jar
```

But I'm not sure that worked.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The properties file is usually part of the native package. I wasn't even aware of an implementation for OSX.

An example of how to set it for Linux is available at [javax.usb FAQ](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/faq.html#linux_imp_jar_file).